# How to force built-in apps to update on a brand new android device?

Tags: google-play-store, 4.4-kitkat, application-autoupdate, motorola-moto-g

I've just unpacked a new phone Moto G 2nd Gen and noticed that the Google Play My Apps is completely empty (it's for my wife, she didn't use android before).

So I updated several essential apps (chrome, gmail, maps) manually by searching them in play store manually and clicking "Update". Now they appeared in the list of apps.

But how can I ensure that all built in apps eventually update automatically as soon as they are not in the list?

It's painful to do that manually - some apps are not even in App Drawer (like Google Keyboard).

**UPDATE**:

Just to let you know: all the built in apps updated automatically and appeared in the list of "my apps"

PS: to be precise only some of them updated, others just appeared there waiting for granting more permissions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open up the PlayStore, open menu and select settings.

Select second option from the top **`auto-update apps`**. Then chose if you want to update from just WiFi or incur data charges.

Sooner or later apps that have updates will want to update.

You can also go into the apps and select auto update if available.

Comment: The issue is that the list of "my applications" is empty since I haven't installed anything manually. Are you sure the built-in apps will eventually update even if they are not in the list?

Comment: If they have any updates they will show up, sometimes it takes awhile. But yes they will.

Comment: This should work, it has for me in the past. You could try clearing all the data from the Play Store and loading it again and see if that helps (it may make it worse). Settings > Applications > Google Play Store > Clear Data. They really should be there in the first place, but I have seen this on a few devices myself. I tended to go an add everything manually as it was a one off thing, but auto update did work for me. Each individual app has it's own 'auto update' option also... May make life a little easier.

Comment: This does work eventually, but I think the point of the question is how to make this happen "sooner" (ie, _now_) rather than "later".